# Time Series Arithmetic in v10.0

Tags: time-series, version-10

The following code lets `FindPeaks` find minima in v10.3-12.0:

```
dat = TimeSeries[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 1}, {4, 2}}];
Normal[-FindPeaks[-dat]]
(* {{1, 1}, {3, 1}} *)
```

but fails in v10.0:

```
(* FindPeaks::arg -- Message text not found -- *)
```

What's the problem and how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently the ability to do arithmetic on `TimeSeries` was added some time after v10.0 (maybe v10.1 based on the docs). There is a new section in the v10.3 docs for `TimeSeries > Examples > Scope > Time Series Arithmetic` that says "Numerical, listable functions automatically thread over values of time series".

A workaround:

```
Normal[TimeSeriesMap[Minus, FindPeaks[TimeSeriesMap[Minus, dat]]]]
(* {{1, 1}, {3, 1}} *)
```

Comment: Time series arithmetic rolled with 10.2
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/SummaryOfNewFeaturesIn102.html